# chidren div move down when i type text into

Tags: css

This is my code :

```css
#wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 width: 1200px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

div {
 width: 150px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div>this is test. this is test.</div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add more data to the question to depict what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element displayed as `inline-block` align to its parent baseline, hence it moves down when it has content.

Giving them a `vertical-align: top` value will fix that.

Another option is to drop the inline block and give the `wrapper` `display: flex`

```css
#wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: flex;
 width: 1200px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

div {
 width: 150px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 margin-right: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div>this is test. this is test.</div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

always remember to define `vertical-align` for `inline-block` element.

```css
#wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 width: 1200px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

div {
 width: 150px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; /* add this always with inline-block */
 margin-right: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div>thisd ihd sofjdlkfj dlkfjdlkfj d</div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your div's css ;D